# Core Data save not completing before next screen is displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

My iOS app has two screens that are showing a problem:

On the first screen, the user takes a photo. This photo is resized (using UIImage-ResizeMagick) to a thumbnail, 58 pixels high. So a pretty small image.

This image is then converted to NSData and saved to a core data record. I then save the context and display the next screen (actually, I pop back to the root controller.)

This second screen is supposed to display a list of the items already added and photographed. Unfortunately, most of the time (but not all of the time) it does not display the last item. The item is eventually saved in the database and will be displayed the next time the second screen is shown, but it seems like the core data save is not quick enough... the screen is displayed before the data is available to be pulled out of the database.

As I indicated above, sometimes the save **is** quick enough, and the item is displayed on the second screen immediately, so it does seem to be a timing issue.

What is the proper way to 'wait' for the database to be updated, before displaying the second screen?

```
UIImage *theImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

// RESIZE IT
UIImage *thumbNailImage = [theImage resizedImageByHeight:58];
theImage = nil;

// save image to tag
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbNailImage);
self.appDelegate.currentTag.photo_data = imageData;
[self.appDelegate saveContext];

// pop back to Home page
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: Instead of thinking in terms of the application 'waiting' for something to happen, think in terms of dynamically updating the UI in response to changes to the model. Using an instance of Core Data's `NSFetchedResultsController` class can automate most of that for you.

Comment: So I set up a NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification on the second screen, expecting to get a notification *after* the view appeared. But the notification was firing much earlier than that. Turns out the solution I needed was to call reloadData in ViewWillAppear, to refresh the table. Duh. Anyway, thanks! Setting up the notification put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Core data has two means of performing changes on a Context. `[NSManagedObjectContext performBlock:]` and `[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:]`.

If you really want a synchronous save, add another method to your appDelegate called saveContextAndWait. Then in this method you can perform exactly what you did in your save, just make sure you wrap the [NSManagedObjectContext save:] method in a performBlockAndWait:.

Happy coding